# Filter on collection

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Is there way to filter collection, e.g.

```
class Company{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="company", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    public $users;

}
```

on way to check that company have users. But i need to filter on company side, so send request `/api/companies?somefilter`.

So point is there way to check is collection empty?

Comment: Could you share the relevant Controller code for `/api/companies` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean column in companies where you set to true when create a user relation.

So you can add a BooleanFilter to you company entity for check companies which have users.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties={"hasUsers"})
 */
```

Or you can create a CustomFilter where you input true o false and get companies with users throught queryBuilder

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-doctrine-orm-filters

```
    <?php
    // api/src/Filter/RegexpFilter.php

    namespace App\Filter;

    use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractContextAwareFilter;
    use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
    use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

    final class RegexpFilter extends AbstractContextAwareFilter
    {
        protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
        {
            // otherwise filter is applied to order and page as well
            if (
                !$this->isPropertyEnabled($property, $resourceClass) ||
                !$this->isPropertyMapped($property, $resourceClass)
            ) {
                return;
            }

            $parameterName = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName($property); 
// Generate a unique parameter name to avoid collisions with other filters
            $queryBuilder
                ->andWhere(sprintf('REGEXP(o.%s, :%s) = 1', $property, $parameterName))
                ->setParameter($parameterName, $value);
        }

        // This function is only used to hook in documentation generators (supported by Swagger and Hydra)
        public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
        {
            if (!$this->properties) {
                return [];
            }

            $description = [];
            foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
                $description["regexp_$property"] = [
                    'property' => $property,
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'required' => false,
                    'swagger' => [
                        'description' => 'Filter using a regex. This will appear in the Swagger documentation!',
                        'name' => 'Custom name to use in the Swagger documentation',
                        'type' => 'Will appear below the name in the Swagger documentation',
                    ],
                ];
            }

            return $description;
        }
    }
```